# Multivariate time series model using MARSS package (or maybe dlm)

Tags: r

I have two temporal processes. I would like to see if one temporal process (X_{t,2}) can be used to perform better forecast of the other process (X_{t,1}). I have multiple sources providing temporal data on X_{t,2}, (e.g. 3 time series measuring X_{t,2}). All time series require a seasonal component.

I found MARSS' notation to be pretty natural to fit this type of model and the code looks like this:

```
Z=factor(c("R","S","S","S")) # observation matrix
B=matrix(list(1,0,"beta",1),2,2) #evolution matrix
A="zero" #demeaned
R=matrix(list(0),4,4); diag(R)=c("r","s","s","s")
Q="diagonal and unequal"
U="zero"
period = 12
per.1st = 1 # Now create factors for seasons
c.in = diag(period)
for(i in 2:(ceiling(TT/period))) {c.in = cbind(c.in,diag(period))}
c.in = c.in[,(1:TT)+(per.1st-1)]
rownames(c.in) = month.abb
C = "unconstrained" #2 x 12 matrix
dlmfit = MARSS(data, model=list(Z=Z,B=B,Q=Q,C=C, c=c.in,R=R,A=A,U=U))
```

I got a beta estimate implying that the second temporal process is useful in forecasting the first process but to my dismay, MARSS gives me an error when I use MARSSsimulate to forecast because one of the matrices (related to seasonality) is time-varying.

Anyone, knows a way around this issue of the MARSS package? And if not, any tips on fitting an analogous model using, say the dlm package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to represent my state-space model in a form adequate to use with the dlm package. But I encountered some problems using dlm too. First, the ML estimates are VERY unstable. I bypassed this issue by constructing the dlm model based on marss estimates. However, dlmFilter is not working properly. I think the issue is that dlmFilter is not designed to deal with models with multiple sources for one time series, and additional seasonal components. dlmForecast gives me forecasts that I need!!!

In summary for my multivariate time series model (with multiple sources providing data for one of the temporal processes), the MARSS library gave me reasonable estimates of the parameters and allowed me to obtain filtered and smoothed values of the states. Forecast values were not possible. On the other hand, dlm gave fishy estimates for my model and the dlmFilter didn't work, but I was able to use dlmForecast to forecast values using the model I fitted in MARSS and reexpressed in dlm appropriate form.